# How to prove $K \subset L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is closed and convex?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $K \subset \mathbb{R}$ be $K= \{f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C} | f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}) \text{ and } f(x) \in \mathbb{R} \text{ for almost every } x \in \mathbb{R} \}$. I have to show that $K$ is a closed and convex subset of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. 
Proof for $K$ is convex: Take two functions $f,g \in K$ at random. Take $t \in [0,1]$. We know that for $tf$, $(tf)(x)$ will be an element of $\mathbb{R}$ for almost every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ (because $f \in K$ and scalar multiplications are internal). The same holds for $-tg$. It now follows that the sum of functions in $K$, remains in $K$, so $tf + g -tg= tf +(1-t)g \in K$. This proves that $K$ is convex. 
Now I still have to prove that $K$ is closed, but I don't know how to do this. I know that a set is closed if its complement is open, so I need that $L^2(\mathbb{R})/K$ is open. And this set is open if for every $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})/K$, there exists an $\epsilon >0$ such that $g \in L^2(\mathbb{R})/K$ when $d(f,g)<\epsilon$.  But that's the furthest I can get...
Can anyone help me out with verifying my proof for convex and helping me further with my proof for closed? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: For the sum, you can add that considering $A=\{x|f(x)\notin\mathbb{R}\}$ and $B=\{x|g(x)\notin\mathbb{R}\}$ are of measure 0 then $A\cup B$ is also of measure 0, then work on the complementary.

Comment: For closed, perhaps you can consider a sequence of functions from K converging in $L^2$ and use the Riesz-Fischer theorem and that a countable union of measure zero sets is measure zero.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeColette, thanks! I think I somewhat found an answer by proving that any converging sequence in K has its limit in K